# How to get the value in the pre-set text field?

Tags: php, html

Good Day People,

I am a newbie PHP programmer, I have a problem on how I can get the value in one of my text field which is already preseted. when I submit the form, I receive this error:

```
 Notice: Undefined index: requestor in C:\xampp\htdocs\SetUpFileForm\output.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: dateSubmitted in C:\xampp\htdocs\SetUpFileForm\output.php on line 18
```

here's my code My goal here is to auto populate the requestor field with the one who is currently logged in:

```
<?php $user = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname; ?>
    Requestor:<input type="text" name="requestor" value="<?php" echo $user; "?>" disabled="yes">
```

Thanks a Lot,

CheekeeDee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `disabled` attribute, use `readonly` attribute:

```
<?php $user = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname; ?>
Requestor:<input type="text" name="requestor" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" readonly />
```

Comment: @user3819288 of course, it wont look like a disabled field, which can be a misleading text field, just style it with CSS to make it look like uneditable. just a suggestion

Answer (score 1):

**YOU WILL NOT ABLE TO GET THE VALUE OF ANY DISABLED FIELD OF HTML IN PHP.**

Undefined warning message comes when you are using the index that is not been defined or that doesn't exists in the $_REQUEST array.

What you can do is print_r you _REQUEST array like this:-

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

check if requestor or dateSubmitted is the index for this array.

AND 
you should check first if an array elements value is set and not empty like this:-

```
$requester = '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['requestor']) && !empty($_REQUEST['requestor'])) { // By doing this there will be any warning like undefined index, and its a good practice too
  $requester =  $_REQUEST['requestor'];
}
```

Hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you used php echo inside your input tag

try this

```
<?php $user = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname; ?>  
Requestor:<input type="text" name="requestor" value="<?php echo $user; ?>" disabled/>
```